# Best practices for displaying status of optional fields that are not filled out by the user?

Tags: forms, empty

Lets say we have an app that currently requires manual entry of:

- **Hours**
- **Current Firmware Version**
- **Compatible Objects (hardware)**
- **Serial Number**

If the user elects not to fill in this information, or maybe even just some of it, what are best practices to display the current statuses? Leave them Blank, N/A, Unknown, Empty, Unavailable? Should each of these fields be considered independently or should we return a uniform, consistent result? The goal is to have the person fill in all of this information but it isn't required.

- **Hours** n/a
- **Current Firmware Version** n/a
- **Compatible Objects (hardware)** n/a
- **Serial Number** n/a

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on the visualisation of the data.
Will it be shown in a readonly form or in a card or list view?

I use it like this for a form:

[image]

In a cards view the empty fields are just not shown:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to respond. I'll try to get in the habit of adding screen shots and being more specific in the future. It will be presented in a list view, kind of like the list I created in the description, but the values will be underneath the labels. 

It was suggested to me by a colleague offline that I use "--" to represent data not entered. I think that works well for my needs in this case.